# Ошибка при установке на Ubuntu библиотеки ROS Kinetic

Tags: ubuntu, ros

Пытаюсь установить ROS Kinetic согласно инструкции на оффсайте на Ubuntu, все отлично идет до шага 1.4 в котором при вводе "sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full" получаю такой ответ:

**Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей

Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Невозможно найти пакет ros-kinetic-desktop-full**

Пробовал с разных машин, с удаленного сервера, один и тот же результат.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вероятно, вы пропустили строку `ROS Kinetic ONLY supports Wily (Ubuntu 15.10), Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04) and Jessie (Debian 8) for debian packages.`

Comment: А `ros-desktop-full` ставится?